# How do I get data entered from a user which gets parsed in JSON into a Javascript file that already loads another set of JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, parsing

I'm trying to make a little flashcard game that allows someone to customize a set of flashcards by entering their own questions and answers through a `<textarea>` field via HTML.  I am stuck on how I can get this data  to link to a javascript file that actually runs the flashcard game.  The javascript file that runs the game already ready has a default set of JSON data that is linked to that particular javascript file.  How would I go about swapping these sets of JSON data so the user use the flashcards with the questions and answers they have created?

Here are some visuals and code to help you understand what is going on here:

The `<textarea>` shows where a user can enter their own questions and answers.

[image: A user enters whatever questions answers they want through this form (I've chosen Italian for this particular case!).]

Then a user can click the button "Create flashcards" and the data that was in the  tags gets parsed into JSON like this:

[image: Data gets parsed into JSON]

I have a file titled flashcards.js that already has a default set of flashcard data that is being loaded from a JSON file.  Here is the code that does this:

```
var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";
var cardIndex = 0;
var qs;
var numCards;
var maxIndex;
var isFlipped = 0;
var colorIndex = 0;
var colorClasses = ['c0','c1','c2','c3'];

(a bunch of code to make the game work in between)

function init() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(jsonObject) {
        qs = jsonObject;
        numCards = qs.length;
        maxIndex = numCards-1;
        displayCard();
    });
}
function displayCard() {
    $("#card").fadeOut(400,function(){
        colorIndex = getRandomInteger(0,3);
        $("#card").addClass(colorClasses[colorIndex])
        isFlipped = 0;
        var newHtml = "<h2>Question Words</h2>";
        newHtml += qs[cardIndex]["q"];
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = newHtml;
    }).fadeIn(400);
}
```

That piece of code outputs something that looks like this:

[image: The flashcard game page generated from the corresponding javascript and html files]

To sum it up, what I'm basically asking is how do I take the JSON data that is created from clicking the button "Create flashcards" and make it load using my flashcards.js file, or if there is anyway to dynamically swap the user created JSON data with this variable :

```
var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";
```

If you need any more information to help understand what is going on here, please don't hesitate to ask.

Any input, help or advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you can push the questions to a GET param on the html page's url. This would allow user-creation and sharing without a centralized server, but also limits the total text length of the question to about 4kb. you can use tinyURLs to get around that in some cases, but older browsers and proxies won't play along...

Comment: You will need a backend process to save the `json` file data. JS cannot save it, as it runs locally on the client.

Comment: if data is only needed for user to interact with....can use localStorage. Use `JSON.stringify(array)` to store and `JSON.parse` to turn back to array when retrieving

Comment: @dandavis Can you explain in more detail how I could possibly do this?  Thanks.

Comment: for example, if all the user-created questions are on the same form location.hash=$(form).serialize(); in ready, you look at location.hash, and if present, parse it and restore the form value or feed it directly to the question interface like you use getJSON. you can use JSON instead of serialize(), or convert the two; i'm sure there are lots of jQuery plugins for that.